# .Net Core 2.0 Authentication Behind Reverse Proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kubernetes, openid-connect

I have a .NET Core 2.0 application in a Kubernetes cluster behind an Nginx Reverse Proxy.  I currently have all of my services (.NET Core and otherwise) successfully authenticating via [Oauth2-Proxy](https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy) with Azure Active Directory.

This works fine on a larger level, but I lose the ability to use role and claims based authorization since I do not have the authentication set up in my app specifically.

Is there any way to set up authorization in my .NET application while utilizing the authentication handled by Oauth2-Proxy?  Would the only way to handle this be to have the app authenticate again when more specific authorization rules are required?

Comment: hi did you find a solution to this? I'm facing the same issue. Did you end up letting oauth2_proxy handle authentication while using the forwarded token header to perform authorization in app?

Comment: @JHub  I am also facing the same issue? did u guys have any luck?

Comment: @Hadindaka I am also facing the same issue? did u guys have any luck?